# SELECT complexo com cinco+ tabelas

Tags: php, sql

Galera, boa noite.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de busca, e a consulta deve ser realizada EM TODAS as tabelas existentes. Acontece que pra cada tipo de resultado existe uma apresentação, por exemplo:

```
if($cat == 'a'):
    echo 'mostra isso';
elseif($cat == 'b'):
    echo 'mostra assim';
else:
    echo 'mostra outra coisa';
endif;
```

Antes eu tinha uma unica tabela para todas as informações, e muitos dos campos ficavam vazios, e na hora da seleção, utiliza do campo CATEGORIA para exibir de acordo, conforme o exemplo passado anteriormente.

Gostaria de saber como deveria ser o select, e como utiliza-la no PHP.

Estrutura das tabelas *(é um site religioso)*

**TUC_ARTICLES**

articles_id
articles_title
articles_description
articles_text
articles_image
articles_visits
articles_slug
articles_date
articles_dateModified

**TUC_PONTOS**
pontos_id
pontos_title
pontos_description
pontos_letter
pontos_visits
pontos_slug
pontos_date
pontos_dateModified
pontos_url
pontos_orixa

**TUC_ALBUNS**

albuns_id
albuns_url
albuns_image
albuns_date
albuns_dateModified
albuns_slug

Como eu criaria uma consulta SQL para todos as tabelas, e como eu iria diferenciar, para poder exibir de acordo?
Caso o resultado seja da tabela articles, mostra assim, se for da tuc_pontos, mostra de outro jeito, e por ai vai...

O que pensei foi em criar um campo categoria em todas as tabelas, mas ficaria redundante demais, pois se tivesse 1000 registros na tabela tuc_articles, todos os registros teriam o mesmo valor..

Então a dúvida extra é essa: tem como saber de qual tabela vem o resultado, pra poder manipular os dados de acordo com sua respectiva tabela?

O que tentei até agora:

```
$search->Read("SELECT * FROM tuc_articles, tuc_pontos WHERE ((`articles_title` LIKE '%".$a."%') OR (`articles_text` LIKE '%".$a."%') OR (`pontos_title` LIKE '%".$a."%') OR (`pontos_letter` LIKE '%".$a."%')) ORDER BY articles_id DESC");
```

PS: O teste acima é genérico, usei apenas duas tabelas e dois campos de cada uma.

Answer (score 1):

Opa!

Uma possível solução seria usar o [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). A query ficaria mais ou menos assim (não testada):

```
SELECT "article" as categoria, articles_id as "id", articles_description as "description", articles_text as "article_text", NULL as "pontos_letter"
    FROM tuc_articles
    WHERE (`articles_title` LIKE '%".$a."%') OR (`articles_text` LIKE '%".$a."%')
UNION
SELECT "ponto", pontos_id, pontos_description, NULL, pontos_letter
    FROM tuc_pontos
    WHERE (`pontos_title` LIKE '%".$a."%') OR (`pontos_letter` LIKE '%".$a."%')
ORDER BY categoria ASC;
```

Retornaria um result set assim:

```
categoria | id | description | article_text | pontos_letter
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
article   | 1  | desc A...   | text A...    | NULL
article   | 2  | desc B...   | text B...    | NULL
ponto     | 1  | desc C...   | NULL         | letter A...
ponto     | 3  | desc D...   | NULL         | letter B...
```

Comment: A resposta está parcialmente correta. Porém, surgiu-me uma dúvida: Quando dou o var_dump, aparece exatamente como disse, um array com categoria e id, e ai eu consigo fazer o IF. Acontece que o select me limitou a utilizar só categoria e ID, e agora não sei como resgatar as outras colunas da tabela.. Como proceder? Eu quero exibir de uma forma se for article, de outra se for ponto.. De qualquer forma, agradeço até então, e peço desculpas pela demora de retorno. Abraço!

Comment: Se você quer colunas diferentes, parece-me que a única opção é fazer mais de um query, um select para cada categoria.

Comment: Eu pensei nisso desde o começo, e até então não seria um problema para criar as query.. Acontece que ao meu ver, tal prática seria errada.. O que acha? Alias, como procederia com a situação?

Comment: É tudo uma questão de necessidade. O ideal é sempre minimizar o número de queries, mas a depender da sua necessidade perante sua estrutura de dados (no seu caso parece, visto que você quer resultados diferentes extraídos da mesma tabela), não há outra alternativa se não fazer mais de uma query. E se isto vai impactar na performance, somente conhecendo sua estrutura, número de usuários, estrutura de servidores, estrutura da sua aplicação, ou até testes de stress etc.

Comment: Mas olhando sua resposta acima, se você quiser somente adicionar colunas, é só adicioná-las ao select (editei a resposta) de ambos os select's da union, desde que sejam do mesmo tipo (na resposta, é a coluna `description`). Se não for do mesmo tipo, só retornar null, como eu fiz acima (não conheço sua estrutura, mas assumi que `pontos_letter` e `articles_text` não são do mesmo tipo e vão retornar em colunas diferentes.

Comment: Compreendi. Da forma com que destes a opção, acredito que o "correto" ou "menos pior" seria a criação de várias queries.. Acontece que não há muita relação entre as tabelas, a não ser o ID e TITULO.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42346/discussion-between-thiago-barros-and-mrlew).